# Draw over MS Forms border

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I'm having a bit of a problem here. I'm trying to draw something on the entire screen, I have a fullscreen form with no visible borders, however, I'm unable to draw on the borders location so there will be about 20+ pixels space with nothing drawn on it at the edges. I figured I am able to expand the window size so it goes over the screen from the bottom and right side, but you can not set the position to be smaller than 0,0 so the top and left border still block my drawing.

to put it simple: How can I draw on the borders?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to get rid of the border entirely.  You can draw your own simulated border as needed.

To do that, set the ControlBox property to *false*.  Set the form's Text property to string.Empty.  Set the border to FixedDialog to make the form unresizable.

In order to still be able to move the form you must override WndProc like this:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
{
    switch (message.Msg)
    {
      case 0x84: 
          message.Result = new IntPtr(0x2);
          return;
    }

    base.WndProc(ref message);
}
```

That code tricks Windows into thinking that mouse clicks on the non-client area are actually on the title bar.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645618%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Did this, no help really. The borders are gone, although I had them gone already earlier, but there is that small empty space at left and top of the screen I can not draw to because that's where the borders would be if they'd be there. And setting the form position to lets say 0,0 actually sets the borders edge to that position, which means the actual form I can draw to is not there, leaving empty space I can not draw to.